# Enable Migration from Package Manager Console in Custom Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have to enable migration using package manager console in visual studio 2013.
The problem is that there is already a CustomMigration Folder which contains all migration files. So how should I enable that CustomMigration Folder and add my migration files to CustomMigration Folder?

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration class constructor add this line:

```
this.MigrationsDirectory = "Path\\CustomMigration";
```

Comment: public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"CustomMigrations";
        }

Comment: when I fire command   Enable-Migrations it is creating another folder Migrations . I Don't want that , I want to enable my CustomMigration Folder

Comment: enable-migrations -EnableAutomaticMigration:$false -MigrationsDirectory CustomMigrations -

Maybe with the enable command itself, you may have to add the -Force also